# Proving the commutativity of a ring with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\left(A,\ +,\ \times \right)$ be a ring such that $1_A$ is the identity in $\left(A,\ \times \right)$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two elements in $A$ such that:
$$\begin{cases}
ab+ba=1_A \\
a^2b+ba^2=a
\end{cases}$$

I need to prove that ab=ba. Since the elements of a ring are per def. not invertible I did not know how I can approach it. Any hints how to get started

I'm also interested knowing under which assumptions are the elements of $A$ $\times-$invertible

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary

Comment: So, just to be clear, $\Bbb Q$ with standard addition and multiplication would _not_ be such a ring, because we have, for instance, $a = 3$ and $b = 5$ with $ab + ba = 30\neq 1_{\Bbb Q}$? Or would it _be_ such a ring because there exists numbers like $a = \frac32, b = \frac 13$ with $ab + ba = 1_{\Bbb Q}$?

Comment: You cannot prove that $\cdot $ is commutative. For example, $A $ might be any noncommutative $\mathbb Q $-algebra with $a = 1$ and $b = 1/2$. Perhaps you only want to show that $ab = ba $ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg If $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary and the equation holds then the ring $\left(A, +, \times \right)$ must be commutative.

Comment: Suppose the two equations hold for **any** $a,b$. Then they hold for $b=1$ and so $a+a=1$. That holds for any $a$, so we also have $ab+ab=1$ for any $a,b$. But $ab+ba=1$ and so $ab=ba$ for any $a,b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $ab+ba=1_A$, we get $a^2b+aba=a$ and subtracting the second equation gives $(ab-ba)a=0$. Now, consider $a$ and $(ab-ba)$. Then, this pair satisfies your first equation as well. So $$(ab-ba)a+a(ab-ba)=1.$$ Since $(ab-ba)a=0$, we have $a(ab-ba)=1$. Now, multiply $(ab-ba)a=0$ by $(ab-ba)$ from the right. So, $$0=(ab-ba)a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)1=ab-ba.$$ Hence, $ab=ba$.

Comment: under which assumptions are the elements of  ×−invertible

Comment: @AyoubFalah The ring is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If the equations hold for any $a,b$, then we can take $b=1$ to get $a+a=1$. That holds for any $a$, so we have $ab+ab=1$ for any $a,b$.

But $ab+ba=1$, so $ab=ba$. That proves commutativity.

But multiplying $a+a=1$ by $b$ we get $ab+ab=b$. We also have $ab+ba=1$, and $ba=ab$, so $b=1$ for **all** $b$.

In other words the ring is only commutative because it is trivial.

Comment: Oh, the ring is trivial. That's a nice observation.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thank you for you contribution! In order to get $a+a=1_A$ you substituted $b$ with $1_A$. That is fine. But I dont know how did you conclude that $ab+ab=1$ for **any** a, and **b**

Comment: @AyoubFalah Suppose $rs=t$. Taking $a=t,b=1$ in the first equation we have that $t1+1t= 1$ and so $t+t=1$. But $t=rs$, so $rs+rs=1$. That holds for any $r,s$. Another way of expressing that fact is that $ab+ab=1$ for any $a,b$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Sorry! We get the equality $a+a=1_A$ exactly under the assumption that $b=1_A$ Hence we cannot conclude its arbitrariness from that. Concerning the last question. As soon as as get this done, I would go back to your reply. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AyoubFalah Yes, we used that assumption to get $a+a=1$. But $a$ is **arbitrary**. The result holds for any $a$.

Answer (score 1):

This proves it for any particular $a$ and $b$ that satisfy these equations regardless of whether the equations are satisfied by all elements of the ring. Multiplying the first equation by $a$ once on the left and another on the right and solving the equations each time yields $$ a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a=0 $$
Multiplying the first equation on the left by $a$ and on the right by $b$ yields $$aabb+abab=ab \tag{1}$$And multiplying it on the left by $b$ and on the right by $a$ gives $$baba+bbaa=ba \tag{2} $$ Multiplying $(ab-ba)a=0$ on the right by $b$ gives $abab=baab$ and multiplying $a(ab-ba)=0$ on the left by $b$ gives $baab=baba$ so $baba=abab$ And what remains is to show that $aabb=bbaa$. To do this, we multiply $ a(ab-ba)=0$ on the right by $b$ to get $aabb=abab$. Now multiply the equation $(ab-ba)a=0$ on the left by $b$ to get $bbaa=baba$. So $bbaa=aabb$.

Comment: How do you get $a(ab-ba)=(ab-ba)a=0$?

Comment: Multiply the first equation on the left by $a$ and solve the equations to get $(ab-ba)a=0$. Do the same again but this time multiply by $a$ on the right instead to get $a(ab-ba)=0$.

Comment: $ab+ba=1$ multiplied by $a$ yields $aab+aba=a$. Not $(ab-ba)a=0$. Not sure what you're doing.

Comment: Solve $aab+aba=a$ simultaneously with $a^2b+ba^2=a$.

Comment: Okay. Why is $baab+bbaa = ba $? typo in first term?

Comment: Yes, sorry I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think it works now

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Nice argument!